# Anchor link not working

Tags: html, anchor

I've encountered weird problem with anchor links. I have some on a page, and they suddenly stopped working (checked in chrome and firefox).

I noticed that after clicking anchor, let's say `<a href="#news">`, address changes to `http://mydomen.net/index.html#/news` and anchor doesn't work. If i manually remove that `/` after `#` and open new link it works as intended, but adds `/` again.

Did I miss some changes in HTML? Or what could it be? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add/change anything? Could you provide your pages URL/the source code, so we can find the problem?

Comment: The `/` has to be coming from somewhere in your code.

Comment: I haven't touched code for sure, already checked git - no changes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Still don't know what caused this, but renaming anchor target to `<div id='/news'>` worked.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility is that this is coming from either your script (but you are only talking about HTML, so there is no clue for that) or URL rewriting on your server.

There is absolutely no possibility for plain HTML with your provided example code to behave like this.

(Browser extension is not an option since you tried different browsers)